# R line chart: multiple observations of 2 different treatments

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I made multiple observations of my plants (one per week) and divided the plants into 2 groups (with and without treatment). My data structure looks like this:

```
Treatment   Leaf Area 1 Leaf Area 2 Leaf Area 3 Leaf Area 4 Leaf Area 5
none        2.411545455 13.02745987         
yes         1.199545455 0.412511147         
none        2.448363636 28.56727482 51.49511341 49.38664803 15.63761378
yes         2.797454545 23.49791914 31.97397924 39.60835617 8.544331072
```

I want to create a line chart similar to the following. Can anyone please help me? I don't really know where to start looking.

[image: Example line chart]

Comment: What have you tried so far? The plot you've inserted into your question is from the `ggplot2` library. It's a pretty basic plot to create, provided your data is set up properly. We'd be able to help more if you provided some sample data, too.

Comment: ggplot(data, aes(x=Week, y=Leaf Area, fill=treatment)) + geom_boxplot() 

I tried something like that but I realize my data structure is in the wrong format. However, I'm not really sure if I should try a different approach or change my data structure. Also I haven't found an easy way to get to the right data structure and I can't do it by hand.

Comment: Have you looked at the other `geom` values provided in `ggplot2`? You can use `geom_point()` to plot the points and `geom_smooth()` to add lines. A little bit of personal research goes a long way. Note that the `fill` value in your first `ggplot` statement is great for a box plot but you will want to swap that out for `colour` for a `geom_point()` or geom_line()`.

Comment: Please see my updated comment.

Comment: Having your data in the right structure makes all kinds of analyses easier. If you can share some of example data (with `dput()`), we can help you get things set up a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you've got your data set up in "wide" format. I'm not sure if each row is a different plant or what, but what matters is that with each measurement, it looks like you're adding a column. It's much better to add a row rather than a column.

Ideally, a good data frame would be set up in "long" format, where each row is a different observation on a given plant rather than a new column. For example:

```
set.seed(256)

dat <- 
  data.frame(trt = sample(c("1", "2"), 50, TRUE), 
             week =  sample(1:5, 50, TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(area = ifelse(trt == 1, rnorm(50), rnorm(50, 12))) %>%
  arrange(week, trt)

> head(dat)
  trt week       area
1   1    1 -1.8472691
2   1    1 -0.1537133
3   1    1 -0.3528910
4   1    1  1.6109927
5   2    1 11.9489893
6   2    1 10.4330834
...
```

With your data set up like this then a lot of things are truly simple. Creating the plot in your question becomes something like:

```
dat %>%           
ggplot(aes(x = week, y = area, colour = trt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
```

Luckily, it's pretty simple to convert from "wide" to "long" format with the `reshape2` library. You use `melt()` and feed the `melt()` fx which are the ID variables and which are the measurements:

```
set.seed(256)
your_dat <- #Not actually your data, just some stuff in a "wide" format
  data.frame(treatment = rep(c("none", "yes"), each = 2), 
             la1 = rnorm(4), 
             la2 = rnorm(4), 
             la3 = c(NA, NA, rnorm(2)), 
             la4 = c(NA, NA, rnorm(2)), 
             la5 = c(NA, NA, rnorm(2)), 
             week = sample(1:5, 4, TRUE))

library(reshape2)

your_dat <- 
  your_dat %>% 
  melt(id.vars = c("treatment", "week"), measure.vars = c("la1", "la2", "la3", "la4", "la5"))

> head(your_dat)
  treatment week variable       value
1      none    1      la1 -0.07465645
2      none    3      la1 -1.00718773
3       yes    5      la1 -1.05276623
4       yes    1      la1  0.47908588
5      none    1      la2 -0.95751656
6      none    3      la2  0.19835162
```

Once you've got that squared away, pass it all to `ggplot()`:

```
your_dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = week, y = value, colour = treatment)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]

and adjust the rest of the aesthetics as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way:

```
library(reshape2)
dd=melt(data, id=c("tratment","week"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd) + geom_line(aes(x=week, y=value, colour=treatment)) +scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","darkgreen"),
                  name="Treatment")+geom_smooth()
```